# Displaying NOAA Charts in .NET

Tags: .net, mapping

NOAA provides free nautical charts in two formats:

1) "NOAA Electronic Navigational Charts® (NOAA ENCs) are vector data sets that represent NOAA's newest and most powerful electronic charting product. NOAA ENCs conform with the International Hydrographic Office (IHO) S-57 international exchange format"

2) "NOAA Raster Navigational Charts® (NOAA RNCs) are full-color digital images of NOAA's entire suite of paper charts...in the BSB format."

Does anyone know of any open source routines to use and display these formats in Microsoft's .NET?

Comment: While not .NET, here is an open-source, cross platform chartplotter that displays these formats: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencpn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might take a look at SharpMap

- http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap

Comment: SharpMap seems to be the only open source .NET project out there that can read the NOAA S-57 charts.

The discussion forum on codeplex sees reasonable levels of traffic and the source code is updated several times a year.

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to provide good links, such as:

- [ENC](http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/FAQ_ENC.html)
- [BSB](http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/staff/charts.htm)

Why didn't you say you'd looked there and couldn't find anything you could use?